# Swift_IoException Unable to open file for reading yii2

Tags: yii2, email-attachments

I am developing a web application in Yii2. I have attached a file while sending the email. But after attaching the file in email I am facing this error.

[error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT7CB.png)

My code for sending email with attachment goes like this

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom('sender email')
                ->setTo('reciever email')
                ->setSubject('test')
                ->setHtmlBody('test')
                ->attach('path of attachment file')
                ->send();
```

I am really facing a big problem please help.

Comment: are you adding attachments with NULL as value.? SwiftMailer can't automatically detect a NULL 
attachment

Comment: i have given the full path with filename in 
->attach('path of attachment file with filename')
if this does not work then what should i use?

Comment: does you attached file has a html code inside anywhere ??Leaving this file empty might cause the file to be attached as base64.

Comment: no it does not contain any html code in it. Its just a word file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html#file-attachment , the attach() method expects the filename (string) as parameter. To fix your code:

```
$model->attachment = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'attachment');

if($model->attachment) {
    $message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom([ Yii::$app->user->identity->email => 'Sample Mail'])
    ->setTo($model->email)
    ->setSubject($model->subject)
    ->setHtmlBody($model->content);

    foreach ($model->attachment as $file) {
        $filename = 'emailattachments/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension; # i'd suggest adding an absolute path here, not a relative.
        $file->saveAs($filename);
        $message->attach($filename);
    }

    $message->send();
}
```