# Unable to open file for reading in Yii2 swift mailer

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

Am trying to embed an image to a view using swiftmailer in yii2 but it returns an error of Unable to open file for reading

This s what i have tried
In the model

```
public function sendAccountActivationEmail($user)
{
    return Yii::$app->mailer->compose('signup', ['user' => $user,
             'successimage' => Yii::getAlias("@web/uploads/siteimages/
                               emails/signup.png")])  //this is path to img

        ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' colors'])
        ->setTo($this->email)
        ->setSubject('Account activation for ' . Yii::$app->name)
        ->send();
}
```

In the view file that is signup.php i have

```
 <img src="<?= $message->embed($successimage); ?>">
```

Where am i going wrong, I have check on [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165209/swift-ioexception-unable-to-open-file-for-reading-yii2)  but offers clue on attaching an image not embedding an existing file. On the [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html) they provide the above method but it fails to work

Comment: Are you able to display the same image in a regular view ??

Answer (score 2):

> You need to supply the full path to uploads not a relative path
>   because that is going to be interpreted as relative to class file that
>   tries to open your attachment [Swift-mailer problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531195/2097862)

You can solve the problem by using `@webroot` instead.

```php
'successimage' => \Yii::getAlias("@webroot/uploads/siteimages/emails/signup.png")
```